# Is there a way to see Meta Participation?

Tags: support, meta

So I noticed the moderator election thread today, and I noticed the nifty little info boxes they had down at the bottom (this is Fabian's):

```
meta participation
questions: 7 / +13
answers: 9 / +38
```

Is this total information available elsewhere? I don't think I'd make a good mod, and have no intention of nominating myself, so I don't think it wise for me to submit a "nomination" solely so I can view my meta participation numbers.

If there is a way to view this data, does one exist for the parent site as well?

Comment: Support would've been the proper tag if you're just asking "Is this possible" rather than "Can this be implemented".

Comment: @Grace -- Suggestion implemented!

Answer (score 2):

With proper maths, this can be done.

You can get the question and answer values by checking your [Meta profile](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer). Then, simply tally up all of the scores of your posts to get your total value in both answers and questions.

You can take a bit of a shortcut and approximate your Meta participation by using tag stats. All Meta questions must have one of four tags, so if you check the top users pages for [**discussion**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/topusers), [**bug**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers), [**support**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/topusers), and [**feature-request**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/topusers), you can reduce the calculation to a simple 4-number addition. Now, because of how negative posts and Community Wiki are handled, this isn't necessarily a complete match for the stats shown on elections. But if you just want a quick idea, it's faster.

Comment: The former part also works for the parent site, naturally, but scales horribly since you'll have a lot more posts there. And there are no required tags, so there is no shortcut approximation either.